# jQuery UI Draggable - why am I getting improper ids from e.srcElement.id only on occasion?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am incredibly confused.  Right now, I have a draggable set to:

```
$('li.drag').draggable();
```

But once is a while, I will grab an element and it will return the parent div or the parent li's id when I call e.srcElement.id on my droppable:

```
$('h3.drop-target').droppable({
    accept: 'li.drag',
    drop: function(e) {
        alert(e.srcElement.id);
    }
});
```

This is very strange, as it will work fine for the EXACT same elements on some occasions, then I will refresh and it will error, usually just on one or two, on the same ones it was just successful on.  Any ideas why I am am getting sporadic behavior?

jQuery 1.8.2 and UI 1.8.24

Comment: What happens on version 1.9.x?

Comment: Tried UI 1.10 and it actually didn't work as well, wouldn't let me drag/drop an element back and forth over more than one Droppable()

Comment: The reason `srcElement.id` doesn't work at "random" is because it's based on where the cursor is at the time of the drop, which may not actually be the droppable, especially if you have a high snap tolerance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may come a tad late but in case anyone else comes here and needs an answer. This has worked for us:

Using "ui.item.context.id" instead of "srcElement.id"